# Какой ЯП предпочитаете в разработке автотестов на Селениум?

Tags: selenium, test-automation

Решаем, на чем делать автотесты на Selenium. Смотрел статистику на Github и Stackoverflow, вижу так ситуацию:

1. В пользу Java работает то, что сам Selenium написан на Java, и самое большое сообщество.
2. В пользу Python - большое сообщество и то, что язык не связан с мейджорами.
3. В пользу C# - хорошие перспективы развития языка.

   - прочие яп сильно уступают и по размерам сообщества, и по кол-ву реализованных проектов.

Но у последнего есть и издержки: необходимость приобретения лицензий.

Условия такие: автотесты сайтов, запускать проекты скорее всего будем на локальном компьютере, но в перспективе возможно и на сервере.

С какими проблемами вы сталкивались, как их решали?

Comment: слишком абстрактно. Юзайте то, что вам нравится. Как будут пробелемы - ищите в интернете. Не находите - задаете вопрос по конкретной проблеме

Comment: все-таки хочется на старте принять правильное стратегическое решение, метод проб и ошибок я конечно тоже применяю, но не каждый же раз.

Comment: Я к тому, что таким вопросам не место на ruSO ( http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask )

Comment: вы еще ruby забылы. да без разницы на каком языке. главное чтобы ты этот язык хорошо понимал и быстро смог написать

Comment: Согласен со всем вышесказанным, но есть огромный плюс в сторону java - огромное количество туториалов. Ещё и плюшки по работе с Jenkins и генерацией красивых отчётов..

Comment: О каких лицензиях речь?

Comment: @pontekorvo нет никакой необходимости приобретения лицензий для C#. Язык сам по себе бесплатен. Платные только некоторые IDE (как и в случае с Java). Берете бесплатный Visual Studio Community Edition или Visual Studio Code и вперед.

Comment: @pontekorvo могу точно сказать, что выбор языка - наименьшая из проблем при написании тестов :)

Comment: С таким подходом, что при выборе технологий смотрят на "статистику на ****", страна так и будет отставать от запада лет на 20.

Comment: А вообще важен не язык, а тестовый фреймворк/DSL. И лучший, как обычно, разработали на Ruby -- называется RSpec. Даже на JS портировали -- Jasmine называется.

Comment: Вот серьёзно, вас в последнюю очередь должно интересовать наше мнение. Тесты кому-то ведь писать придётся. Поэтому язык скорее всего выбирать придётся не вам, а QAA, который будет, собственно, тесты и писать. Возможно, совмещая с ролью разработчика.

Answer (score 2):

Самый распостраненный язык для селениум веб драйвер -- Java. В его сторону и советую смотреть именно из-за того что будет проще найти работу в даном стеке, когда перестанешь работать в даной конторе. Кроме того и искать людей в даном стеке будет проще всего твоей конторе в будущем.

На втором месте -- руби и питон, шарп.

Если фриланс -- руби и питона больше чем шарпа.

> Но у последнего есть и издержки: необходимость приобретения лицензий.

ничего приобретать не нужно.

Если хочется использовать шарп лично для себя - вполне неплохой выбор. Одна из лучших IDE -- это большой плюс. Отдельно советую использовать последний Community, подхоботится что бы работал CodeLens, поставить с Resharper (платный) и использовать синтаксис c#6. Нереально удобно.

Но не смотря на написанное -- советую джаву все равно.

PS: В случае с джавой -- лучше использовать Intellij Idea как IDE. Все кто на нее переходит с еклипса назад не возвращаются.